# Date not binding to view model on postback using ASP.NET MVC and Telerik UI Web Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, asp.net-mvc-5

Here's the kendo ui grid parameterMap that is building the postback url parameters:

```
parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
  if (operation != "read") {
    // post the seasons so the ASP.NET DefaultModelBinder will understand them:
    // Example:
    // seasons[0].Season="Fall"
    // seasons[0].Method="Archery"
    // ... etc ...

    var result = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < data.models.length; i++) {
      var record = data.models[i];

        for (var member in record) {
          result["seasons[" + i + "]." + member] = record[member];
        }
    }

    return JSON.stringify(result);
  } else {
    return JSON.stringify(data);
  }
}
```

Using Fiddler, I can see that the date properties are posting to the action method in the following format:
  *Mon Jan 01 1 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)*

But when I set a breakpoint on the *Update* action method in the controller, every other property in the model binds *except* for the three date properties.

The view model:

```
public class SeasonViewModel
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Season { get; set; }
    public string Species { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public string Subseason { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReportEndDate { get; set; }
}
```

And the **update** method of the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(IEnumerable<SeasonViewModel> seasons)
    {
        using (SeasonEntities context = new SeasonEntities())
        {
            foreach (var season in seasons)
            {
                TBLKSEASONDETAIL tsd = new TBLKSEASONDETAIL
                {
                    TSDID = season.ID,
                    TSDYEAR = (short)season.Year,
                    TSDSEASON = season.Season,
                    TSDSPECIES = season.Species,
                    TSDMETHOD = season.Method,
                    TSDSUBSEASON = season.Subseason,
                    TSDSTARTDATE = season.StartDate,
                    TSDENDDATE = season.EndDate,
                    TSDREPORTENDDATE = season.ReportEndDate
                };

                context.TBLKSEASONDETAILs.Attach(tsd);
                context.Entry(tsd).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
            return Json(null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question and it works now.

As stated in the [Kendo documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tutorials/ASP.NET/Hello%20Kendo%20UI/asp-net-hello-kendo-ui-part-2):

> This is because Dates (which are notoriously awful to work with) are formatted for JavaScript.

The site then gives an example to demonstrate how to reformat the date:

```
options.BirthDate = kendo.toString(new Date(options.BirthDate), "MM/dd/yyyy");
```

In my particular case, I simply had to check if the property was a date or not, and format it accordingly:

```
if (member.toLowerCase().indexOf("date") >= 0) {
  var d = new Date(record[member]);
  result["seasons[" + i + "]." + member] = kendo.toString(d, "MM/dd/yyyy");
} else {
  result["seasons[" + i + "]." + member] = record[member];
}
```